# How to switch back from one layout to the parent layout in the same activity

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm creating a quiz app. Users are shown clues and have to guess the answer.

I have an activity with two layouts nested inside the "parent" constraint layout. The reason for this is that I needed a custom layout so I could pull rows from three columns from an SQLite database and display them in the app. These are the clues.

The top part of the activity is therefore this layout and the bottom part of the activity is another constraint layout that contains the buttons (refresh button to refresh the clues and check answer button) and the text view allowing the user to enter their text.

When I enter my activity, everything works fine. Clues are displayed and all buttons work.

When I press the refresh button (to refresh the clues), it refresh's the clue and then stops the buttons in the bottom layout from working, i.e I press them but nothing happens. My theory is that when I run the method that, it switches everything to the top layout and that stays (disabling the buttons in the bottom layout).

The bit of code that refresh's the clues, and therefore is causing the issue is this:

```
 public void getPlayerHistory() { // Method used to get player history from DatabaseAccess.java,
                                 // assign to list and place in the ListView

    setContentView(R.layout.view_player_history); //the main layout everything is being displayed in

    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    databaseAccess.open();

    userList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data = databaseAccess.getListContents();

    int numRows = data.getCount();

    while (data.moveToNext()){
        user = new User(data.getString(0), data.getString(1),
                data.getString(2));
        userList.add(user);
    }
    databaseAccess.close();
    com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass adapter =
            new com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.i("get player history", "playerHistoryFunction Run");

}
```

I think the issue is coming from this line

```
        com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass adapter =
            new com.example.transfergame.ThreeClass(this, R.layout.list_adapter_view, userList);
```

where I switch to my custom layout, but I'm not exactly sure what to code to then switch back to my parent layout.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue actually came from

```
     public void getPlayerHistory() { 

    setContentView(R.layout.view_player_history);
```

For some reason, setting this within this method, and not the onCreate() method was causing the issue. I have taken this out and put it in the onCreate() method and now everything runs fine.